# Expectation value of the electromagnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, vacuum

According to wikipedia, the operator of the electromagnetic field is given by:
$$E \propto \sum_k \sqrt{k}(a_k^{+}e^{-ikr}+a_ke^{ikr})$$

wouldn't that mean that the expactation value of $E^2$ is infinite for the vacuum?
$\langle 0|E^2|0\rangle = \infty $?
And what is meant by vacuum fluctuations in general? Does it just mean that $\langle 0|E^2|0 \rangle \neq 0$?

Comment: That is why you renormalize the expectation value of the Hamiltonian, as with other quantum fields.

Comment: Also the vacuum fluctuations don't influence the expectation value of the energy, only the standard deviation of its measurement.

Comment: @Slereah but $\langle 0|E^2|0 \rangle \neq 0$ means that we have vacuum fluctuations or what do we exactly mean by it?